# Why is GWT ArrayList of String objects truncating text with an ampersand?

Tags: gwt, special-characters, truncate

I'm using GWT on the client side.  I store String objects in an ArrayList instance, and when I add the value "AT&T", it only seems to be storing "AT".  I suspect this is the result of the ArrayList truncating the text due to the ampersand, but I have yet to write a smaller proof-of-concept to be sure.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?

GWT 2.1.1
Tomcat 7.0.5
Firefox 5.0.1

So this test succeeds:

```
        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        test.add( "testing&123");
        Window.alert( test.get(0) + " - " + test.get(0).contains("&") );
```

My code effectively does this:

```
String test = "AT&T";
MyApp.getInstance().getDataStore().add( test );
Window.alert( test + " - " + MyApp.getInstance().getDataStore().getItems().get(0) );


public void DataStore.add( String item ) {
   itemsList.add( item );
}
public ArrayList<String> getItems() {
   return itemList;
}
```

The output is "AT&T - AT".  So if the ArrayList is not the problem, is it the method calls?

Comment: What exactly means "it only seems to be storing AT"? How did you see that?

Comment: What is your DataStore? It looks like it's dropping the "&T" in there. If it's just an ArrayList<String> can you try to reproduce this without the indirection of the DataStore, and see if your code is dropping it somewhere else?

Comment: @Jason: I'm trying this now...

Comment: As Ionut said, how do you know that is storing only "AT"? Are you displaying the value of the array on the screen? If you do that, probably you only see "AT" because you need to escape the contents of the array before displaying them.

Comment: @Luismahou He's using an alert() to display the value as retrieved from the DataStore so it doesn't need to be (un-)escaped for his test case. My guess is something's happening in the DataStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out it was an interaction between my History Manager and the DataStore class.  A very strange situation that no one could have helped me with given the limited amount of information I had provided.